# My while loop goes back to the top after running the code.How Can I make it that it starts again after the 'again;?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dice game but after the game is complete I would like it to start again with the question "Do you want to roll the dice again" instead of going to the first statement. This is as far as I have gotten and am not sure what to do to correct the code. Any help is much appreciated!!

```
import random
dice_number = random.randint(1, 6)
play = True

while play:
  roll_dice = input("Would you like to roll the dice?")
  if roll_dice.lower() == 'yes':
    print(dice_number)
  else:
    print("Let us play later then.")
    break

  again = str(input("Do you want to roll the dice again?")) 
  if again == 'yes':
     print(dice_number)  
  if again == 'no':
    play = False
    print("It has been fun playing with you.")
    continue
```

Comment: `Would you like to roll the dice?yes` so after this `Would you like to roll the dice?no` after I say no you would go back to `Do you want to roll the dice again`?

Comment: Hello QBear! may I ask what do you mean by this `after the game is complete`, you mean when you say "no" to "Would you like to roll the dice?"?

Comment: What I was trying to do was after rolling the dice once, "Would you like to roll the dice" "Yes", "Do you want to roll the dice again?" "Yes" then it would go back to the statement "Do you want to roll the dice again?' instead of "Would you like to roll the dice?" Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer but @dimay, got it first & his code works based on your objective :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random
dice_number = random.randint(1, 6)
play = True
first = True

while play:
  again = input("Would you like to roll the dice?") if first else str(input("Do you want to roll the dice again?")) 
  first = False
  if again.lower() == 'yes':
    print(dice_number)
  else:
    print("Let us play later then.")
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
import random
dice_number = random.randint(1, 6)
play = True

started = False

while play:
    if started:
        again = str(input("Do you want to roll the dice again?"))
        if again == 'yes':
            print(dice_number)
        elif again == 'no':
            play = False
            print("It has been fun playing with you.")
            break

    else:
        roll_dice = input("Would you like to roll the dice?")
        if roll_dice.lower() == 'yes':
            started = True
            print(dice_number)
        else:
            print("Let us play later then.")
            break
```

Sample Output:

```
Would you like to roll the dice?yes
3
Do you want to roll the dice again?yes
3
Do you want to roll the dice again?yes
3
Do you want to roll the dice again?yes
3
Do you want to roll the dice again?yes
3
Do you want to roll the dice again?no
It has been fun playing with you.
```